# What are the differences among django_redis, channels_redis, asgi_redis and redis server?

Tags: django, redis, django-channels, django-redis

I am new to Django and right now i'm learning Django async with Channels. I have noticed some programmers use channels_redis for their projects, some use django_redis, some use asgi_redis and i found redis server in google. Is there any difference among those libraries?

Comment: redis is used to provide the milliseconds for an operation. Depending on the prefix, it will be pointed towards another operation as far as I understand.

Comment: I want to know why they use different types of redis libraries. I searched google but couldn't find any topic related to this. I think all those libraries implement redis functionalities in my django project. But why do they come with different names?

Answer (score 1):

Django-redis is a service that caches backend redis data. Redis data is accurate time information about events, for instance connections made to a server or database. So django-redis is an api that is used for mentioned purpose. Django channels is a django feature that allows the framework to work with websockets directly, work with IoT protocols, chatprotocols, and more. These utilities rely on the services of the ASGI-redis API. The ASGI-Redis server must be connected with the Django channel in order to perform it's tasks.

You can read more about the subject here:

https://realpython.com/getting-started-with-django-channels/